# Receiving a DynamicLink firebase Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I m developing an android application in which i want to    able the user to publish a post with a social network or with email using DynamicLinks Firebase(If the application is already installed in the device the post activity will be opened directly,if not le link will open the play store page of the application).I followed these steps:
1/I have created a dynamilink in firebaseConsole and i have used "https://rc4vd.app.goo.gl/XktS" as shortlink
2/a button to send the dynamiclink, this is the code

```
btnShare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                            sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "I invite you to my challenge\n\n" + "https://rc4vd.app.goo.gl/XktS?d=" + databaseReference.getKey());
                            sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                            startActivity(sendIntent);    
 }
```

3/At the reception of the dynamic link

```
FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().getDynamicLink(getIntent()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<PendingDynamicLinkData>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<PendingDynamicLinkData> task) {

                            Uri shortLink = null;
                            if (task.getResult() != null) {
                                // --> shortLink = task.getResult().getShortLink(); 
                                String postId = (shortLink.toString()).substring(shortLink.toString().indexOf("=")+1);

                                //[declare the intent]
                                Intent intent = new Intent(Home.this,MyPostPage.class);
                                //[Set intent extras]
                                intent.putExtra("ref", PostId);
                                //[start the activity with extras]
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(Home.this, new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "getDynamicLink:onFailure", e);
                        }
                    });
```

the problem is "shortLink = task.getResult().getShortLink();" does not exist and i can only have the deepLink.I want to know if there is a way to have the short link and thanks

Answer (score 0):

Rather than generating a link in the console, and then appending an argument, you should create a dynamic link in your app which includes the parameter in the target (long) URL.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/android/create is the documentation page for the Android API there.